# How do I filter Choice FK in Forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want filter a choice in a form according user_logged. Here is my models.

```
#models.py
    class Store(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class StoreManager(models.Model):
        store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name='store', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class StoreLogo(models.Model):
        store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name='store', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Store')
        image = photo = models.FileField()
```

First I created a Store, after that I Associate a StoreManager to a Store, and then I want in a forms add a ImageLogo, so in that forms, in field Store, I want list only a Store what user has associated.

```
Store = (SuperMarket Store), (ClothesStore)
StoreManager = John(SuperMarket Store), Julian(ClothesStore)
StoreLogo = John (can only view SuperMarket Sotre)
StoreLogo = Julian(can only view ClothesStore)
```

I'm using CBV(generic.CreateView).
There is my views.

```
#views.py
class AddPhotoOnEstablishment(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = StoreLogo
    fields = ['store', 'image']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register:establishment_list')
    context_object_name = 'object_name'
```

I want, if John has associated to Store and logged in the system, when he add a Image logo, the field Store only appear the Store he has associated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this link](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_form_kwargs) will help. it explained methods and attributes of CreateView class. in the render_to_response method you can get the current user using this code:

```
self.request.user
```

and check if it's associated with the store logo you're sending as response.